# SMTP server for sending thousands of mail notification on daily basis

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, sendmail

I'm in the process building a web application which is has a potential to send thousands of email on daily basis (most of it is system notification emails)

I'm using dedicated server for start but I'm thinking to use such as a smtp server to handle the sendmail process. Not just to reduce the server load but the most important thing is I don't wan't my server IP blacklisted in any spam list such as spamhaus.org

Can you suggest me what the best deal for this situation? 
Options that I have so far are :

- Using goggle app smtp with premier account. This is the option I prefered but I'm not sure whether google has such limitation that does not fit my situation
- Using commercial smtp server (If this the best option, can you suggest me any reliable service for this?)

Comment: Try [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/). Google Apps isn't designed to handle mass mailings, so I wouldn't count on great deliverability.

Comment: @Michael Thanks! Definitely will try it. Any other suggestion anyone?

Comment: Oh, I should also add [PostageApp](http://postageapp.com/) and [Postmark](http://postmarkapp.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend a commercial solution because then your taken out of the maintenance and if you do get blacklisted you can enlist their support team to take care of it.

I've used [campaign monitor](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/) and had very good success with them.  The rates are comparable and the interface is very easy to use.  This is more of a small business solution.

I've also used [Responsys](http://www.responsys.com/suite/index.php) and [Yesmail](http://www.yesmail.com/).  These are more enterprise solutions and might be a little overkill for what your looking for.

Comment: +1 for Campaign Monitor! Great product to rely on and recommend to clients, and a good API if you want to sync contacts and basic info with your web app.

Comment: Please note that I'm not about to send marketing emails / newsletter. It's about notification email from my app, just like facebook does. The system will send related users email when user doing activities such as posting image, respons status, tagging this and that and many more

Comment: I agree it's not for newsletter type emails but if your sending to "customers" you will want to have the capability of staying out of their spam/junk mail boxes as well as a support system that will help you if you do get blacklisted at an ISP. Campaign Monitor's pricing is very nice for smaller companies.  The last send I did with them was around 300 users and it cost me $8.  The more you send to the cheaper per email address it gets.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding black lists: if you are cautious, and do not do silly things, like sending 5000 mails once on a fresh IP address, than you will not be blacklisted. For the case of accidental blacklisting you should have a reserve IP address or a reserve server.

A few thousand mails is not a noticeable load on modern hardware. Just think about it: if you send 5000 mails per day that means only a single mail per 17 seconds.

That said I am not against using an external mail service for sending notifications at all, I just have no such experience.